# How to get the particular part of string matching regexp in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've got a string `Unnecessary:12357927251data` and I need to select all data after colon and numbers. I will do it using Regexp.

```
string.scan(/:\d+.+$/)
```

This will give me `:12357927251data`, but can I select only needed information `.+` (`data`)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Anything in parentheses in a regexp will be captured as a group, which you can access in `$1`, `$2`, etc. or by using `[]` on a match object:

```
string.match(/:\d+(.+)$/)[1]
```

If you use scan with capturing groups, you will get an array of arrays of the groups:

```
"Unnecessary:123data\nUnnecessary:5791next".scan(/:\d+(.+)$/)
=> [["data"], ["next"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use parenthesis in your regular expression and the result will be broken out into an array.  For example:

```
x='Unnecessary:12357927251data'
x.scan(/(:\d+)(.+)$/)
=> [[":12357927251", "data"]]
x.scan(/:\d+(.+$)/).flatten
=> ["data"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `/(?<=\:)\d+.+$/`

It changes the colon to a positive look-behind so that it does not appear in the output. Note that the colon alone is a metacharacter and so must be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: I get error `SyntaxError: compile error
undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=:)\d+.+$/`

Comment: Haha. Ruby's Regular Expression engine probably does not implement look behinds then. The other answers will get you through the problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying to get the string 'data' from your string, then you can use:

```
string.match(/.*:\d*(.*)/)[1]
```

String#match returns a MatchData object. You can then index into that MatchData object to find the part of the string that you want.

*(The first element of MatchData is the original string, the second element is the part of the string captured by the parentheses)*

Answer (score 0):

Using IRB

```
irb(main):004:0> "Unnecessary:12357927251data".scan(/:\d+(.+)$/)
=> [["data"]]
```